# Is there a way to embed a command prompt into the Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

Basically I'm looking for something like the "Visual Studio Command Prompt", but which can be docked as a tab or otherwise moved about like any other Visual Studio panel.

Does such a thing exist?

I'm looking for something like [PowerConsole](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67620d8c-93dd-4e57-aa86-c9404acbd7b3/) but which would let me run msbuild from whithin the IDE.

Comment: can't you run `msbuild` from inside powerconsole?

Comment: @akira: Perhaps you can, but it seems you have to specify the full path of the msbuild executable (or screw around with %PATH%?). Plus a ton of environment variables need set for the various compilers to work correctly. MSVS includes a batch script to do all this, but I don't think that'll run in PowerShell.

Comment: you can do this, very easily and i ll give you an answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

If using NuGet, in Visual Studio click Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

Comment: YES!  Thank you for answering the question the OP had.  The other answer says Use Powershell.  Well, if I was comfortable using powershell, I would, but I like cmd.  I never realized that the PM console worked this way.

Comment: In VS2017, that is indeed a PowerShell host. And some bat script I have to work with just do not work inside it.
It is a bit lame it seems we still cannot have a regular command prompt embedded into VS.

Answer (score 2):

instead of searching any further: just use the powerconsole and incorporate the settings of the "visual studio command prompt".

the visual studio command prompt is nothing more but:

1. cmd.exe
2. feed with vcvarsall.bat

so, all you have to do is execute vcvarsall.bat and interprete the result of that into your powershell. luckily this can be achieved very easily:

- Scott Hanselmann has setup his powershell prompt escpecially for VC, search the post for "get-batchfile" to get an idea of how to use vcvarsall.bat:

  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AwesomeVisualStudioCommandPromptAndPowerShellIconsWithOverlays.aspx
- Get-Batchfile originates somewhat from here: http://allen-mack.blogspot.com/2008/03/replace-visual-studio-command-prompt.html
- And SO has something on the same topic:

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124753/how-i-can-use-powershell-with-the-visual-studio-2010-command-prompt

this should you get going, no need for cmd.exe, really.

Comment: I'm confused -- the powershell console uses powershell, not the command processor (`cmd.exe`) -- I don't even need the vcvarsall bit -- I just want a plain terminal window.

Comment: If you want to use cmd.exe from within PowerShell, just run cmd.exe from within PowerShell. I don't know if there are any limitations with this, but I've never run into an issue where something works in the Command Line but not by running cmd.exe from PS.

Comment: This was all good for 2011. Does anyone have the answer relative to 2018?